# How to add image url field to an html form in django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a donation web application. Users are able to fill out a form and there donation is submitted into the database, I was wondering how I can have the user submit a url of an image and save it in the database, and then render it on another page. For example (the full form is down bellow), if the user fills out the form and submits a url like https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481349518771-20055b2a7b24?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cmFuZG9tfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80, how would I save it to the database and render it out on another page? All help is appreciated. My code is down bellow.

Html Form:

```
<label class="label-input100" for="image">Image</label>
                <div class="wrap-input100">
                    <input id="phone" class="input100" type="text" name="image" placeholder="Please enter the url of your image" required>
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
```

View:

```
if request.method == "POST":
        image= request.POST['image']
        return redirect('thankyou.html')
```

Model:

```
image = models.ImageField(null = True, blank = True)
```

I am always on my computer so feel free to ask if you have any questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def saveImage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        image = request.FILES.get('image')
        new_image = <Image_Model>.objects.create(
            image = image
        )

        return redirect('/somewhere/')
    return render(request, 'new_image.html',)
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Create a folder in the app level of your project...name it "static"
2. Inside the "static" folder, create another folder, name it "images"
3. Open the SETTINGS.PY file and paste the code below

SETTINGS.PY

```
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/images'
```

4. Open the URLS.PY file in the same folder as the SETTINGS.PY and paste the code below

   `from django.conf import settings`

   `from django.conf.urls.static import static`

`urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

HTML FORM

`<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{%destination url%}">`

`<input name="image" type="file">`

`</form>`

Comment: This doesn't help me at all, I want the user to give me an image link, and then I will save it to the database and render it on another screen