# How to convert image url into ImageField - Django

Tags: python, django

am creating a donation web application. Users are able to fill out a form and there donation is submitted into the database, I was wondering how I can have the user submit a url of an image and save it in the database, and then render it on another page. For example, if the user fills out the form and submits a url like https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1481349518771-20055b2a7b24?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cmFuZG9tfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80, how would I save this to the database as an Image and not a URL? I should then be able to render it out on another page.

Html Form:

```
<label class="label-input100" for="image">Image</label>
                <div class="wrap-input100">
                    <input id="phone" class="input100" type="text" name="image" placeholder="Please enter the url of your image" required>
                    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                </div>
```

My view: (There is a lot of stuff here that do not pertain to my question, I just included it in case it is needed)

```
def donate(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        title = request.POST['donationtitle']
        phonenumber = request.POST['phonenumber']
        category = request.POST['category']
        quantity = request.POST['quantity']
        location = request.POST['location']
        description = request.POST['description']
        date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
        ins = Donation(title = title, phonenumber = phonenumber, category = category, quantity = quantity, location = location, description = description, user=request.user, date = date )
        ins.save()
        # New part. Update donor's stats.
        UserDetail.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(donations=F('donations') + 1)
        UserDetail.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(points=F('points') + (quantity * 2))
        return HttpResponseRedirect( '/thankyou/', )
    return render(request,'donate.html')
```

I know there has to be stuff saved in the model, my model is down bellow. It contains data from the form and has nothing started on the image yet.

```
class Donation(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=12)
  category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  quantity  = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True,)
  location = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,)       
  description = models.TextField()
  date = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=999)
  user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

Thank you to everyone who helps me with my question, I really can't figure it out and I appreciate all help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add image url field to an html form in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68353448/how-to-add-image-url-field-to-an-html-form-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view, you send a request to get the image like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137817/how-to-download-image-using-requests), and then save the received binary in the image field so you can render it later.

Comment: This doesn't help me, I want to download the image from a url, I know this is possible in Django, the example you showed me is regular python.

Comment: You can still use regular Python in Django and as far I know, this can't be done in Django. because imagefield deals with image binary directly.

Comment: I have seen it done with Django before, and I know that it is possible. your answer does not answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
response.raise_for_status()
avatar = ContentFile(response.content, name='image.png')
```

And `avatar` can be passed to File/ImageField in models :)